# Object: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using:

```
Qt Creator 3.0.1
Based on Qt 5.2.1 (GCC 4.8.2, 32 bit)
Built on Apr 9 2014 at 09:14:10
```

This release is part of an SDK for the ACR890 all in one mobile smart card terminal.

The handset is running linux, I'm not what the distribution is, if I run:

```
uname -a:
```

I get:

```
Linux am37x-evm 2.6.37 #1 Wed Nov 22 18:16:43 HKT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

In my application I create a worker thread to check the status of the WiFi network:

```
mpWiFiScan = new clsWiFiScan(this);
//Connect slot to scan signal
connect(mpWiFiScan, SIGNAL(scanResultsReady(QString))
           ,this, SLOT(networkScanResults(QString)));
mpWiFiScan->setScanState(SS_SCAN);
mpWiFiScan->start();
```

This is called at the end of the main window constructor.  In the main window class I have the slot to receive the network scan results:

```
void clsMainWnd::networkScanResults(QString strResults) {
    qDebug() << "clsMainWnd::networkScanResults:";
    qDebug() << strResults;
}
```

Here is the WiFi Scan thread body:

```
void clsWiFiScan::run() {
    int intSleepCounter = 0;
    bool blnLastPowerState;
    QString strResponse;

    while ( true ) {
        eScanState eState = eGetScanState();

        if ( eState == SS_TERMINATE ) {
            break;
        }
        if ( eState != SS_SCAN ) {
            continue;
        }
        bool blnPower = blnGetPowerStatus();

        if ( blnPower != true ) {
    //Is the "wpa_supplicant" process running?
            if ( clsSOAP::lngPIDof(this, lsWiFiScan::mscstrWPAsupplicant) == 0 ) {
    //No, start it now
                mpcAcsWiFi->reloadWpaSupplicant();
            }
    //Can we ping Google?
            if ( clsSOAP::blnPingTest(this) != true ) {
    //No, ensure WiFi power is on
                wifi_pwr_on();
            }
    //Can we get a server response?
            strResponse = mpcAcsWiFi->status();

            if ( strResponse.contains("wpa_state=COMPLETED") ) {
    //Yes, turn on power
                setPower(true);
            }
            while ( eState != SS_TERMINATE
                 && eState != SS_PAUSE
                 && intSleepCounter < mscintReloadWPAsupplicantTime) {
                sleep(mscintTempSleepDuration);
                intSleepCounter += mscintTempSleepDuration;
                eState = eGetScanState();
            }
            if ( intSleepCounter == mscintReloadWPAsupplicantTime ) {
                setPower(true);
            }
            intSleepCounter = 0;
        }
    //If the power was off and now its on...
        if ( blnLastPowerState != true && blnGetPowerStatus() == true ) {
            mpcAcsWiFi->scan();
            strResponse = mpcAcsWiFi->scanResults();
            emit scanResultsReady(strResponse);

            while ( eState != SS_TERMINATE
                 && eState != SS_PAUSE
                 && intSleepCounter < mscintScanInterval ) {
                sleep(mscintTempSleepDuration);
                intSleepCounter += mscintTempSleepDuration;
                eState = eGetScanState();
            }
        }
    //Update the last known power state
        blnLastPowerState = blnPower;
        intSleepCounter = 0;
    }
    emit scanFinished();
    delete mpcAcsWiFi;
    setScanState(SS_TERMINATED);
}
```

The problem is when I run this application I see lots of the following:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is clsWiFiScan(0xd8208), parent's thread is Thread(0xb8c38), current thread is clsWiFiScan(0xd8208)
```

Then later:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QProcess(0xd82e8), parent's thread is Thread(0xb8c38), current thread is clsWiFiScan(0xd8208)
```

QProcess is called in the functions:

```
bool clsSOAP::blnPingTest(QObject* pParent, QString strURL) {
    QProcess* pProc = new QProcess(pParent);
    pProc->start("ping", QStringList() << "-c" << "1" <<
                                          "-w" << "10" <<
                                          strURL);
    while( pProc->waitForFinished() != true ) {
    }
    int intExitCode = pProc->exitCode();
    delete pProc;
    return (intExitCode == 0);
}
```

strURL has a default value of 8.8.8.8 for Google.

```
long clsSOAP::lngPIDof(QObject* pParent, QString strApp) {
    QProcess* pProc = new QProcess(pParent);
    pProc->start("pidof", QStringList() << strApp);
    while( pProc->waitForFinished() != true ) {
    }
    QByteArray bytOutput = pProc->readAllStandardOutput();
    bool blnOk;
    long lngPID = bytOutput.trimmed().toLong(&blnOk);
    delete pProc;
    return lngPID;
}
```

Everything seems to work ok, but still I get lots of these warnings.

[EDIT]  Based on comments I've changed my class so its now derived from QObject, not QThread.

It now reads:

```
mpWiFiScan = new clsWiFiScan(this);
//In the clsWiFiScan constructor it calls setParent(pParent); where pParent the passed parameter
mpWiFiScan->moveToThread(&mthrdWiFiScan);
//mthrdWiFiScan is a member variable of type QThread
connect(&mthrdWiFiScan, SIGNAL(started())
       ,mpWiFiScan, SLOT(run()));
connect(mpWiFiScan, SIGNAL(scanFinished())
       ,&mthrdWiFiScan, SLOT(quit()));
connect(mpWiFiScan, SIGNAL(scanFinished())
       ,&mthrdWiFiScan, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(&mthrdWiFiScan, SIGNAL(finished())
       ,&mthrdWiFiScan, SLOT(deleteLater()));
mthrdWiFiScan.start();
```

I'm still getting the same messages and I don't see run() getting called at all.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this, is to forget about subclassing `QThread` and just use the [worker object method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details). The mistake many people make when they subclass `QThread`, is that they assume that this object lives in the same thread it is managing. That is not the case.

Comment: The comment above by @thuga is correct and should be heeded.  Regarding the problem/symptoms you're seeing however, you create a `QProcess` on the secondary thread but specify its parent to be the `clsWiFiScan` that lives on the main thread.  Just don't give the `QProcess` instances created in `clsSOAP::blnPingTest` and `clsSOAP::lngPIDof` a parent.

Comment: @thuga  I've tried this now I'm not seeing my thread run at all, I've followed the instructions on the link, my class is now derived from QObject not QThread.

Comment: Did you call `mthrdWiFiScan.start()`?

Comment: @thuga, sorry, yes, just forgot to add it to this post.

Comment: If you using `QThread` this [blog entry is a must](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Comment: @MarekR But also this entry: https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html

Comment: @king_nak in your link author clearly violates the Single Responsibility Principle. With inheritance of `QThread` class does two unrelated things: manages thread and some does some business related logic. So he is clearly wrong. Also I have lots of more trust in official Qt site.

Comment: How do you check if `run` is called?

Comment: @thuga, I have a break point in run which contains a while loop, it never gets hit.

Comment: If `clsWiFiScan` now inherits from `QObject` rather than `QThread` you will need to explicitly declare `clsWiFiScan::run` as a `slot` otherwise the older Qt4 `connect` mechanism won't find it (Do you not see any message along the lines of `"no such slot ..."` at the console?).

Comment: @G.M. I think that has been the problem, run isn't declared as a slot atm, will change that now and report back.

Comment: @thuga, thank you, working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve these issues by calling [QObject::moveToThread()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) and then set the parent.

For example your code that creates the WiFi scanner would change like so.

```
mpWiFiScan = new clsWiFiScan();
mpWiFiScan->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());
mpWiFiScan->setParent(this);
//Connect slot to scan signal
connect(mpWiFiScan, SIGNAL(scanResultsReady(QString))
       ,this, SLOT(networkScanResults(QString)));
mpWiFiScan->setScanState(SS_SCAN);
mpWiFiScan->start();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look and try it out now, do I need to change my class which is currently derived from QThread ?

Comment: Tried it, still the same issues.

Comment: Are you creating some objects inside your `clsWiFiScan` class using that class parent?

Comment: Yes, however I have a destructor for the class the deletes them.  In my class I also use a mutex for access methods to protect class members.

Comment: Have you tried moving those to the `clsWiFiScan` parent thread too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there is one member the is created in the constructor and only reference by the thread itself and deleted in the destructor, nothing else can access this member.

Comment: `mpWiFiScan` lives in the thread it was created in, `mpWiFiScan->moveToThread(this->thread());` will not do anything.

Comment: @thuga is right, I didn't think about that. Maybe moving to `QApplication::instance()->thread()` would be good Using the worker object pattern is better anyway.

Comment: I don't know what is the `this->thread()`, but for me `mpWiFiScan->moveToThread(this->thread());` is a code smell.

Comment: @MarekR yep, thinking about it that line is completely useless since `mpWiFiScan` is already living in that thread. I've fixed it.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza, change the moveToThread to an instance of QThread, e.g. mthrdWiFiScan which is a member of the hosting class and it works, setParent is not required.